# What is a Dire Wolf?

Tags: animals, trope

In many fantasy stories, there are creatures called Dire Wolves.  What's a Dire Wolf, how is it different from existing wolves?

Comment: In the HBO version, they appear to be huskies or malamutes....

Comment: @M. Werner: Dire Wolf *pups* look like huskies or malamutes :). They're supposed to get much much bigger.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dire_Wolf) they're not fictional, although some stories may give them supernatural properties.  They're an extinct species that existed from the [Early Pleistocene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_Pleistocene) to [Late Pleistocene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_Pleistocene) stages (roughly between 1.8 million – 10,000 years ago) in North and South America.  Dire Wolves were one of many [Pleistocene Megafauna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleistocene_megafauna), which are basically large animals that existed at that time, which included sabre-toothed cats, mammoths, giant lemurs, and giant sloths.  Dire Wolves are larger than [gray wolves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_Wolf) (the largest existing type of wolf), averaging 5 ft in length and 240 lbs, although they tended to have shorter legs proportionally than gray wolves.

Comment: I believe they entered sf+f culture through D&D, but it could have been long before that.

Comment: How are you sure that the fossil Dire Wolf wasn't named after some pre-existing usage in fantasy contexts?

Comment: It was named in 1858. It's likely that the generic "Dire X" in fantasy is named for it, not the other way around.

Comment: @Random832 I wasn't talking about contemporary fantasy.  I was talking about something like _Tales From the Brothers Grimm_.

Comment: @Billare Sounds like a good question, "When's the first instance of a 'Dire Wolf' in fiction?"

Answer (score 6):

Generally, "Dire" animals are larger, more vicious versions of existing animals. They're common in RPGs like D&D and other games or fiction with similar fantasy themes. In D&D (at least in more recent editions), in addition to being larger dire animals also tend to have bony plates and spikes.